# Change color of items in spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I want to change the color of items in spinner to say 3 different colors and all the items should be added dynamically.
I am adding items in the spinner through list.
Suppose i have 2 lists and i want to merge both list items in single spinner item but 
both should be of different colors.
My xml file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >`

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#66CCFF"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="abcd"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvMaterial"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/material"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinMaterial"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvWeight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Weight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etWeight"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="Enter Weight"
    >
</EditText>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bAddCat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Add" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bCancelCat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Cancel" />

</LinearLayout>    
</LinearLayout>
```

and Java class is

```
    package com.androidui;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class AddCategory extends Activity {

TextView tv1;
String cat = null;
Spinner spin;
Button add;
Button cancel;
EditText etWt;
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_category);

    tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bAddCat);
    cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bCancelCat);
    etWt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etWeight);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        cat = extras.getString("name");
        tv1.setText(cat);
    }

    addItemsOnSpinner();

    //Onclick listners to buttons
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(AddCategory.this,
                    "Material : "+ spin.getSelectedItem().toString() + "\nWeight : " + etWt.getText().toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    });
}

public void addItemsOnSpinner() {

    spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinMaterial);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Material 1");
    list.add("Material 2");
    list.add("Material 3");
    list.add("Material 4");
    list.add("Material 5");
    list.add("Material 6");

    //Second List
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list2.add("Mat 7");
    list2.add("Mat 8");
    list2.add("Mat 9");

    //Combined List
    List<String> listCombine = new ArrayList<String>();
    listCombine.addAll(list);
    listCombine.addAll(list2);

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listCombine); 

    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


    spin.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
  }

    }
```

Please suggest a method.
Thanx

Comment: You need to write your own class extends from ArrayAdapter. Then modify the getView() Method as you want.

Comment: you can use layout file as spinner elements.. in that you can add your own color formats.

Answer (score 0):

You can try SpannableString for coloring your text  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html